# Stratified sampling for household dataset. Multiple targets or single target?

Tags: stratification

I am new in stratified sampling. I have a regression task to analyse the relationship between income, household size and expenditure, using python. Both income and expenditure are continuous variables, while household size is categorical. I have following questions:

1. I asked chatGPT, it said if it is regression task, it is better to consider 3 variables as stratification targets. I think it is too complex, should I consider 3 variables? (If so, two variables should be enough, since income and expenditure is highly correlated, am I right?)
2. Is converting the variables into categorical variable necessary? If so, I will like to create a new variable called expenditure levels to classify households into different groups, then start stratified sampling.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you have this data already available? If yes, why do you need to sample?

Comment: Seriously, from which aspect do you consider ChatGPT as a stat guru?

Comment: I have data available. I want to do stratified sampling because I am not going to use whole dataset, I jwant to divide the dataset samples into different strata based on expenditure, then randomly picked them for regression task.

Comment: @User1865345, I just try only, and I personally also not really trust AI answers, so I came here for helps. Is ChatGPT bad?

Comment: I won't consider ChatGPT to be a reliable consultant. Period. You can also check the meta discussion [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6423/362671) to get a sense of how deceptive it can be.